# Distribution of nominated stake?

Tags: polkadot

Does anyone happen to know without having to spend time on source searching:

1. A Polkadot nominator with stake N DOT nominates X validators. How the stake is distributed between them for the purpose of electing them as active:

   - every one gets N
   - every one gets N/X
   - one gets N, all the rest get nothing
   - other (what?)
2. A Polkadot nominator with stake N DOT nominates X validators, Y of which are then elected as active. How the stake is distributed between them for the purpose of working (earning profits, being slashed etc):

   - every one gets N
   - every one gets N/X
   - every one gets N/Y
   - one gets N, all the rest get nothing
   - other (what?)

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone happen to know without having to spend time on source
> searching

This article gives insight into how Nominated Proof of Staking (NPoS) works on Polkadot https://medium.com/web3foundation/how-nominated-proof-of-stake-will-work-in-polkadot-377d70c6bd43

> A Polkadot nominator with stake N DOT nominates X validators. How the
> stake is distributed between them for the purpose of electing them as
> active:

This is determined by the NPoS algorithms, which work for fair representation and decentralization. They -

1. Maximize the total amount at stake on the network
2. Maximize the stake behind the minimally staked validator.
3. Minimize the variance of the stake in the active validator set.

When writing this response, the validator with the lowest stake in the active set is backed by 1.5 million DOT, and the average stake is around 2 million DOT.

Let's say you have 10 million DOT and only nominated a single validator. By doing this, you did not give the NPoS algorithm any choice to split the stake among validators, so your entire stake of 10 million DOT will back a single validator in the active set.

Let's say you have 10 million DOT and nominated five different validators. All those five will make it to the active set with your nomination alone. Suppose these validators received nominations from other nominators. In that case, their nominations might be applied to other validators they nominated who might make it to the active set (by the list items 2 and 3 from above).

So, to answer your question, the NPoS algorithms decide how much of your stake backs each validator you nominate. Typically, amounts much lesser than the average active validator stake (2 million DOT) are mapped to a single validator. For example, let's say you nominate 1000 DOT to 16 validators, your stake will likely end up backing only a single validator.

> A Polkadot nominator with stake N DOT nominates X validators, Y of
> which are then elected as active. How the stake is distributed between
> them for the purpose of working (earning profits, being slashed etc)

The NPoS election runs in each era and as I mentioned earlier, a nominator's stake is mapped (most likely) to a single validator or a handful who make it to the active set. The staking rewards or slashing penalties are earned/applied proportionately to the stake applied to each validator. Let's say you nominated 16 validators, and your stake ended up backing one validator. The fate of your staking rewards/slashing penalties is tied to that particular validator in that staking era and is unaffected by the actions of other 15 validators you nominated.

For detailed information, please read these pages on the Wiki:

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-staking

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-staking-advanced

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-phragmen